# Image slideshow. How to make slide effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, slideshow

I am having trouble trying to make the images in my slideshow "slide". The current code only changes the images but I want a slide effect, if you know what I mean. How can I accomplish this?

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {
    myIndex = 1
  }
  x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 3000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<h2 class="w3-center">Automatic Slideshow</h2>

<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">
  <img class="mySlides" src="//via.placeholder.com/350x150/AAFFAA" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="//via.placeholder.com/350x150/FFAAAA" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="//via.placeholder.com/350x150/AAAAFF" style="width:100%">
</div>
```

Comment: Which kind of slide effect are you aiming for? Can you show us what you've attempted?

Comment: Does it have to be in HTML 4.01 or HTML5. I ask as this could be achieved with a Canvas or can be done via a set of preloaded images

Comment: it could be in any